# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest startReport java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

im running this selenium script using maven for extent reports but im getting error:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest startReport
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:276)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.BasicFileReporter.init(BasicFileReporter.java:106)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter.<init>(ExtentHtmlReporter.java:30)
    at com.river.cgyProject.CgyExtentReports.startReport(CgyExtentReports.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setup
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod screenShot
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setup
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod screenShot
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest endReport
SKIPPED: verifyAddContract
SKIPPED: verifyLogin
```

And my code is:

```
public class CgyExtentReports {

     public WebDriver driver;
     public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
     public ExtentReports extent;
     public ExtentTest logger;

     @BeforeTest
     public void startReport() {
         htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("/home/rivertech/Dev/workspace/apache/cgyProject/target/"));
         extent = new ExtentReports();
         extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
         extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "RiverCgy");
         extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Test");
         extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Preetham");
         htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Title of the Document");
         htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Name of the Report Comes here ");
         htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);    
     }

     @BeforeMethod
        public void setup() {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("demo");
        }

     @Test
     public void verifyLogin() {
         logger = extent.createTest("To verify Cloudigy Login");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control inputgray emailInput']")).sendKeys("admin@cloudigy.io");
         driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("test1234");
         driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click(); 
     }

     @Test
     public void verifyAddContract() {
         driver.findElement(By.id("contracts")).click();
         try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         driver.findElement(By.id("pageDropDown")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.linkText("20")).click();
         try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ec2\"]"));
         List<WebElement> rows_table = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
         int rows_count = rows_table.size();

         for (int row=0; row<rows_count; row++){
            List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            int columns_count = Columns_row.size();

               for (int column=0; column<columns_count; column++){
                   String celltext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
                  System.out.println(celltext);

               }
         }   


     }

     @AfterMethod
      public void screenShot(ITestResult result) {
          if(ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus()) {
              try {
                  TakesScreenshot screenshot=(TakesScreenshot)driver;
                  File src=screenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

                  String filename= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss'.png'").format(new Date());
                  File dest=new File("/home/rivertech/Dev/workspace/apache/cgyProject/target/" + filename);
                  FileHandler.copy(src,dest);
                 System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
              }catch(Exception e){
                  System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot"+e.getMessage());

              }
          }
      }

     @AfterTest
        public void endReport() {
            extent.flush();
        }

}
```

Comment: have you checked on which line the NPE occurs?

Comment: `System.getProperty("/home/rivertech/Dev/workspace/apache/cgyProject/target/")` I do not think there is a system property of that name...

Comment: you can add a try catch to get the line with error, but I thinks too it's coming from the getProperty

Comment: @Ehcnalb he can get the line from the stacktrace he posted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the path of your project, just mention:

```java
String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Reports\\index.html";
```